# Achievements and ACL

Tags: parse-platform, acl

I have an Achievement class in Parse and a _User can gain achievement at some place in the game I am working on. For some reason, a _User who does not gain an achievement should not be able to see informations about it.

I know how to implement it in a classic database schema (using a many-to-many relationship) but I was wondering how to implement it in Parse using the permissions and ACLs which have been designed for this kind of matter (I only see how to use ACL for one-to-one relationships).

My idea is to add a Relation column to the _User class. But how to make sure _User can only get informations about Achievement they gained.

Am I obliged to use Cloud Code for this kind of matter?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an associative table, or better, a Parse Relation between the two tables.

https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#manytomany

Add relation column in a class as follow:

[image]

If the relation to a specified achievement exist, than the user could gain his informations

**Edit 1**

Through the ACL, you could do something similar (i use some Obj-C code just to explain):

```
// Having the instance to an existing Achievement object
PFObject* achievement = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kTbAchievements];
[achievement setObjectId:@"mwQipJGpSb"];
[achievement fetch]; // gain full object from Parse server

// Way for get current achievement acl informations
//PFACL* currentAchievementACL = [achievement ACL];

// Creation of ACL for this achivement (just for this example ), otherwise use " 
// [achievement ACL]" for getting existing achievement ACL

PFACL* acl = [PFACL ACL]; // Instance of new Acl object

// allowing read access to user with objectId == userId1
[acl setReadAccess:YES forUserId:@"userId1"];

// allowing read access to user with objectId == userId2
[acl setReadAccess:YES forUserId:@"userId2"];

[achievement setACL:acl]; // assign new created ACL obj
[achievement save]; // updating the achievement


// check for user authorizations
BOOL check1 = [acl getReadAccessForUserId:@"userId1"]; // YES, granted
BOOL check2 = [acl getReadAccessForUserId:@"userId2"]; // YES, granted
BOOL check3 = [acl getReadAccessForUserId:@"userId3"]; // NO, denied
```

This is what you will have in the dashboard for your selected achievement
[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: I know that. Thank you but how do you relate these relations with ACLs ? In fact, I am looking for kind of dynamic ACLs ?

Comment: Ok, i'll edit the answer with a possible ACL solution

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that's scalable ?

Comment: Honestly, i'll probably use a Parse relation, since i can easily add and remove the relation between user and achievement. With the ACL way, i'll going to make huge "json" structure in the ACL fields, and i don't know if it is so performant than a Parse relation, for each row of Achievement class. About the way you add and remove an user from the acl list of a specified achievement, that's pretty quickly and easy as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried about users hacking the Parse database to learn about achievements they don't have? If so then ACLs are a good solution. ACL is to solve security problems.

If instead you want them to only see achievements they have in the UI for the game, then I would simply use relationship to link the achievements. This would then be a filtering problem.

You need to ask yourself if it is a security problem or a filtering problem.